# Cleaner way to handle varags in a @FunctionalInterface?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, type-inference

Consider this interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingFunction<T, R>
{
    R tryApply(T t)
        throws Throwable;
}
```

And this class:

```
public final class Wrapper<T, R>
{
    private final ThrowingFunction<T, R> f;

    public Wrapper(final ThrowingFunction<T, R> f)
    {
        this.f = f;
    }
}
```

With those, I can write:

```
final ThrowingFunction<Path, Path> f = Path::toRealPath;

new Wrapper(f);
```

but I *cannot* write:

```
new Wrapper(Path::toRealPath);
```

The problem is due to [the method prototype](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toRealPath-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-). It *can* take a `LinkOption...` as an argument.

Yet the compiler is able to "coerce" the method reference here. The only way I came up with to mimick this is downright hackish:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingFunction<T, R>
{
    R tryApply(T t)
        throws Throwable;

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface WithVarags<T, V, R>
        extends ThrowingFunction<T, R>
    {
        R tryApplyWithVarargs(T t, V... ignored)
            throws Throwable;

        @Override
        default R tryApply(T t)
            throws Throwable
        {
            return tryApplyWithVarargs(t);
        }
    }
}
```

And then adding a new constructor to the `Wrapper`:

```
public <V> Wrapper(
    final ThrowingFunction.WithVarags<T, V, R> function)
{
    this.function = function;
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do that? That is, can I do "like the compiler" in this case?

Comment: If you want to do like the compiler you have to `new Wrapper((p) -> ((Path)p).toRealPath(new LinkOption[0]));`. Maybe it's easier to solve if you would more explain what you want to get at the end. What you want to achieve with the Path::toRealPath function?

Comment: I tried to retrace your workaround, however, it doesn’t work for me, it actually makes things worse as even specifying the type arguments explicitly doesn’t work then. After all, it’s an uncommon corner case to not having any target type; note that in your question you are not even specifying the diamond operator for the `Wrapper` instantiation. In practice, you will either have a target type or help the compiler like with `new Wrapper<>((Path p)->p.toRealPath())`, however, it seems to be a compiler flaw that it can’t infer types for varargs in method references correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You might specify the types of `Wrapper` at instanciation.

```
new Wrapper<Path, Path>(Path::toRealPath);
```

or

```
Wrapper<Path, Path> wrapper = new Wrapper<>(Path::toRealPath);
```

I think it is not related to varargs. By specifying the types, you are also saying to the compiler to "ignore" the varargs parameter.

---

Note, i saw that you can also "ignore" the return type of the same function:

```
ThrowingBiConsumer<Path, LinkOption[]> biConsumer =  Path::toRealPath;
new Wrapper<Path, LinkOption[]>(Path::toRealPath);


public interface ThrowingBiConsumer<T, U> {
    void accept(T t, U u) throws Throwable;
}
```

Comment: Which is what I do _not_ want to do. Look [here](https://github.com/fge/throwing-lambdas); right now I don't need to.

Comment: I want the result of the method, therefore a `Consumer` is not an option either...

Comment: Yes i understand it was just a side note.